Python httpx log all request headers
How can I log all request headers of an httpx request? I use log level DEBUG nad response headers log fine but there are no request headers in the log. If it matters I'm using async api of httpx lib.

Register an event hook on request.

Use custom event hooks:
import httpx
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
async def log_request(request):
    logging.debug(f"Request headers: {request.headers}")
async with httpx.AsyncClient(event_hooks={'request': [log_request]}) as client:
    response = await client.get('https://httpbin.org/get')

